# Ubuntu 22.10 keyboard layout popup isn't my Logi keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, 22.10

I have a Logitech Logi ERGO K860 keyboard and the Ubuntu 22.10 keyboard popup depicts an upsidedown-L return key and the middle A,S,D... row with twelve keys. My Logi, however, has just eleven on the A,S,D... row with the QERTY... upper row having thirteen keys including at the far right the \ key. Is there any way to get a keyboard layout popup that corresponds to my Logi layout?

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and pick a model which better matches your keyboard. There are quite a few Logitech options.

Comment: I tried this but the actual graphic in the Show Keyboard Layout popup (top panel dropdown) did not change to reflect my Logitech Logi keyboard. My keyboard is as described, i.e., 13-key, while the graphic has a 12-key QWERTY row. Not a big deal, but, yeah...

Comment: Ok. Don't know if it's an intended limitation or a bug.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `setxkbmap -query` then report back please.

Answer (score 0):

Installing solaar really solved all my problems: you can configure really a lot with that. For me lots of thinks worked a lot more as I would expect it by just setting the K860 with Solaar in 'Windows' mode instead of 'MacOS'. But you can change the functioning of each button I think, but I didn't need to dive into that myself. Feel free to let me know if this solves your problems.

Install it by running on the command line:

```
sudo apt install solaar
```

[image: The Solaar application]